# Using Case When in a Join Statement Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I have been trying if it is possible to join two tables conditionally. Below is an example of what I did but it returns an error ORA-00905: Missing Keyword.

```
WITH rejects AS
(
  SELECT
    c.containername
    , c.containerid
    , rlhd.waferscribenumber
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_BLISTER', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_BLISTER
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_CAMTEKREJECTS', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_CAMTEKREJECTS
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_CHIP-OUT', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_CHIPOUT
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_LIQUID_CONTAM', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_LIQUID_CONTAM
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_OPAQUE_CONTAM', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_OPAQUE_CONTAM
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_CORROSION', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_CORROSION
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_CRACKED_OR_BROKEN_WAFER', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_CRACKED_OR_BROKEN_WAFER
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_DIFFUSION_FAULT', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_DIFFUSION_FAULT
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_EDGE_DIE', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_EDGE_DIE
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_EXCESSMETAL', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_EXCESSMETAL
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_EXCESS_PROBE_MARK', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_EXCESS_PROBE_MARK
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_FADED_INK', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_FADED_INK
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_FLY-OFF_DIE', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_FLYOFF_DIE
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_FOREIGN_MATERIALS', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_FOREIGN_MATERIALS
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_GLASSIVATION', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_GLASSIVATION
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_INCOMPLETETRIM', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_INCOMPLETETRIM
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_INK_SPLATTER', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_INK_SPLATTER
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_LASERPINHOLE', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_LASERPINHOLE
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_LASERTRIM', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_LASERTRIM
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_LIGHT_HAZES', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_LIGHT_HAZES
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_METAL_BRIDGE', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_METAL_BRIDGE
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_METAL_VOID', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_METAL_VOID
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_MISALIGN_SCRIBE', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_MISALIGN_SCRIBE
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_OTHERS', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_OTHERS
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_PASSIVATION_FAULT', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_PASSIVATION_FAULT
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_PROBE_DAMAGE', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_PROBE_DAMAGE
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_OVER', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_OVER
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_UNDER', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_UNDER
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_THROWAWAY_DIES', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_THROWAWAYDIES
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_UNPROBE_DIE', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_UNPROBE_DIE
    , NVL(MAX(DECODE(rlhd.LossReasonName, 'WLP_WO_LETTER_EFG', rlhd.totalqty)), 0) WLP_WO_LETTER_EFG
  FROM CONTAINER c
  JOIN a_rejectlothistory rlh ON c.containerid = rlh.historyid
  JOIN a_rejectlothistorydetails rlhd ON rlh.rejectlothistoryid = rlhd.rejectlothistoryid
  WHERE rlhd.specname IN ('8810_DS_VISUAL_INS_WS', '8810_WS_VISUAL_INS_WS', '7202_POST_WAFFLE_PACK_INSPECTION_WS')
  GROUP BY c.containername
           , c.containerid
           , rlhd.waferscribenumber
  ORDER BY c.containername
)

SELECT DISTINCT
  SUBSTR((SELECT(otherdb.pkg_calendar.fncalendar(wl.moveouttimestamp, 'YYYYWW')) AS wwkdate FROM dual), 0, LENGTH((SELECT(otherdb.pkg_calendar.fncalendar(wl.moveintimestamp, 'YYYYWW')) AS wwkdate FROM dual))-2) YEAR
  , SUBSTR((SELECT(otherdb.pkg_calendar.fncalendar(wl.moveouttimestamp, 'YYYYQ')) AS wwkdate FROM dual), -1) quarter
  , SUBSTR((SELECT(otherdb.pkg_calendar.fncalendar(wl.moveouttimestamp, 'YYYYWW')) AS wwkdate FROM dual), -2) WW
  , to_char(wl.moveouttimestamp, 'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS PM') ddate
  , CASE WHEN to_char(wl.moveouttimestamp, 'HH24') > 18 THEN 'C3' ELSE 'A2' END shift
  , c.containername Lotnum
  , wl.productname device
  , lw.wafernumber
  , p.description CATEGORY
  , wl.moveinqty qty_in
  , wl.moveoutqty qty_out
  , DECODE(wl.moveinqty, 0, 'N/A', ROUND((wl.moveoutqty / wl.moveinqty) * 100, 4)) yield
  , NVL(r.WLP_BLISTER, 0) WLP_BLISTER
  , NVL(r.WLP_CAMTEKREJECTS, 0) WLP_CAMTEKREJECTS
  , NVL(r.WLP_CHIPOUT, 0) WLP_CHIPOUT
  , NVL(r.WLP_LIQUID_CONTAM, 0) WLP_LIQUID_CONTAM
  , NVL(r.WLP_OPAQUE_CONTAM, 0) WLP_OPAQUE_CONTAM
  , NVL(r.WLP_CORROSION, 0) WLP_CORROSION
  , NVL(r.WLP_CRACKED_OR_BROKEN_WAFER, 0) WLP_CRACKED_OR_BROKEN_WAFER
  , NVL(r.WLP_DIFFUSION_FAULT, 0) WLP_DIFFUSION_FAULT
  , NVL(r.WLP_EDGE_DIE, 0) WLP_EDGE_DIE
  , NVL(r.WLP_EXCESSMETAL, 0) WLP_EXCESSMETAL
  , NVL(r.WLP_EXCESS_PROBE_MARK, 0) WLP_EXCESS_PROBE_MARK
  , NVL(r.WLP_FADED_INK, 0) WLP_FADED_INK
  , NVL(r.WLP_FLYOFF_DIE, 0) WLP_FLYOFF_DIE
  , NVL(r.WLP_FOREIGN_MATERIALS, 0) WLP_FOREIGN_MATERIALS
  , NVL(r.WLP_GLASSIVATION, 0) WLP_GLASSIVATION
  , NVL(r.WLP_INCOMPLETETRIM, 0) WLP_INCOMPLETETRIM
  , NVL(r.WLP_INK_SPLATTER, 0) WLP_INK_SPLATTER
  , NVL(r.WLP_LASERPINHOLE, 0) WLP_LASERPINHOLE
  , NVL(r.WLP_LASERTRIM, 0) WLP_LASERTRIM
  , NVL(r.WLP_LIGHT_HAZES, 0) WLP_LIGHT_HAZES
  , NVL(r.WLP_METAL_BRIDGE, 0) WLP_METAL_BRIDGE
  , NVL(r.WLP_METAL_VOID, 0) WLP_METAL_VOID
  , NVL(r.WLP_MISALIGN_SCRIBE, 0) WLP_MISALIGN_SCRIBE
  , NVL(r.WLP_OTHERS, 0) WLP_OTHERS
  , NVL(r.WLP_PASSIVATION_FAULT, 0) WLP_PASSIVATION_FAULT
  , NVL(r.WLP_PROBE_DAMAGE, 0) WLP_PROBE_DAMAGE
  , NVL(r.WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_OVER, 0) WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_OVER
  , NVL(r.WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_UNDER, 0) WLP_METAL_SCRATCH_UNDER
  , NVL(r.WLP_THROWAWAYDIES, 0) WLP_THROWAWAYDIES
  , NVL(r.WLP_UNPROBE_DIE, 0) WLP_UNPROBE_DIE
  , NVL(r.WLP_WO_LETTER_EFG, 0) WLP_WO_LETTER_EFG
  , wl.specname
FROM CONTAINER c
JOIN product p ON c.productid = p.productid
JOIN a_wiplothistory wl ON c.containerid = wl.containerid
JOIN a_lotwafers lw ON c.containerid = lw.containerid
LEFT JOIN rejects r ON CASE WHEN wl.specname =  '8810_WS_VISUAL_INS_WS' THEN c.containerid = r.containerid AND lw.waferscribenumber = r.waferscribenumber
                       ELSE c.containerid = r.containerid
                       END
WHERE c.containername NOT LIKE '%TEST%' AND c.containername NOT LIKE '%TST%' AND wl.specname IN ('8810_DS_VISUAL_INS_WS', '7202_POST_WAFFLE_PACK_INSPECTION_WS', '8810_WS_VISUAL_INS_WS')
;
```

Any idea on how can this be achieved? Thank you.

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Answer (score 0):

Your missing keyword is one this line:

```
LEFT JOIN rejects r ON CASE WHEN wl.specname =  '8810_WS_VISUAL_INS_WS' THEN c.containerid = r.containerid AND lw.waferscribenumber = r.waferscribenumber
                       ELSE c.containerid = r.containerid
                       END
```

I would suggest your write this without a `case`:

```
LEFT JOIN rejects r
ON c.containerid = r.containerid AND
   ((wl.specname = '8810_WS_VISUAL_INS_WS' AND lw.waferscribenumber = r.waferscribenumber) OR
    ((wl.specname <> '8810_WS_VISUAL_INS_WS' OR wl.specname IS NULL)
   )
```

In Oracle, a `case` statement cannot return a boolean expression.  You could write the condition as something like:

```
LEFT JOIN rejects r
ON c.containerid = r.containerid AND
   (case when (wl.specname = '8810_WS_VISUAL_INS_WS' then lw.waferscribenumber
         else r.waferscribenumber
    end) = r.waferscribenumber
```

But I think the first method is clearer.